# How weakly open imply open?

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis

When I am seeing the proof of the statement "Let $C$ be a convex set in a normed linear space $X$.
Then $C$ is closed if and only if $C$ is weakly closed."

Proof: Suppose that $C$ is weakly closed. Then $C^c$, the complement of
**$C$ is weakly open and hence open**. Hence $C$ is closed.

my problem is in the 2nd line of the proof written in bold line. How weakly open imply open?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Every open set in the weak topology is open in the norm. This follows from definition of weak topology.

Weak topology is the smallest topology that makes every element of the dual space continuous. Since every element of the dual space is continuous for the norm topology it follows that every weakly open set is open in the norm topology.